# Switch to AR mode by default

Tags: aframe, web-ar

Using A-Frame 1.2.0, the default view when visiting the URL on a mobile phone is a mono VR mode, with buttons to switch to AR and VR.

This mode also allows non-AR GUI elements like HTML buttons to be placed on the screen, they will overlay on top of the scene, with some CSS.

Is it possible to make the default view when visiting the URL just as it is currently, but with the AR camera? I.e. leave the AR and VR buttons, leave whatever is added to the page with HTML and CSS, but turn on the device camera?

Or, if that's not possible, how to switch to the AR mode immediately on load?